# Numerical computation series

Tags: sequences-and-series

In a numerical series following data is given: 
    $$u_1 = 3, v=2\text{ and }s_n=120$$

They ask to find the value of $n$.

First I used the formula: 
$$u_n= u_1 + (n-1) \cdot v       
   \implies u_n= 3 + (n-1) \cdot 2$$

Then I tried to put this formula inside the formula for $s_n$

$$    s_n= n \cdot {u_1 + u_n\over2}$$

When I try to work further with it and insert the data $s_n=120$
I eventually find that 
$$n^2+ 7/2\cdot n -120=0$$

Then I tried to calculate 
$$D =b^2-4ac$$
 and find a very weird answer $1969/4$.

Who can explain where I made a mistake?

Comment: You don't need to put a dollar sign for every single symbol in MathJax. Also, \implies is better than \Rightarrow, as it is longer.

Comment: I am still learning to write like this and also English isn't my native language so thanks for the improvements :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get $2$ there, not $7/2$.

$n^2 + 2n - 120 = 0$

Comment: Thanks, I was able to trace back where in wich step i made the mistake!